# Wildfly Connection pool with PostgreSQL. Getting a JdbcSQLException

Tags: java, postgresql, servlets, jdbc

I'm trying to implement connection pooling for a simple web project that has just one servlet. But for some reason I'm getting a JdbcSQLException org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException:ERROR [stderr] (default task-4) Table "EMP" not found;
This is the first time I'm configuring a connection pool in Wildfly. After some reserch I still can not figure out how to fix this issue. I guess maybe somethig is not configured properly in my Intelij project.
I made the following steps:

- Deployed a JDBC driver (postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc4.jar) in Wildfly;
- Configured a JDBC datasource (Name: PostgresDS, JNDI: java:/PostgresDS);
- Tested the connection (Connection URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/sample_db) in Wildfly;
- Successfully connected to database PostgresDS.

In Intellij project:

- Created a Data Source (also named PostgresDS), successfully connected to the database (URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/sample_db).

But when I'm trying to run a servlet, the JdbcSQLException occurs.

```
[2016-11-27 06:03:38,447] Artifact employees-jsp:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2016-11-27 06:03:38,447] Artifact employees-jsp:war exploded: Deploy took 1 619 milliseconds
18:03:45,222 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4) org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Таблица "EMP" не найдена
18:03:45,222 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4) Table "EMP" not found; SQL statement:
18:03:45,223 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4) SELECT * FROM emp [42102-173]
```

What could I have missed here? Do I need to configure any .xml files in the project?

I'll be grateful for all hints, opinions and critique.

Here is the servlet:

```
    @WebServlet(name = "ServletDS", urlPatterns = {"/ServletEmp"})
public class ServletDS extends HttpServlet {
    @Resource(name = "PostgresDS")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Set up the Printwriter
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/plain");

        // Get a connection to the DB
        Connection myConnection = null;
        Statement myStatement = null;
        ResultSet myResultSet = null;

        try {
            myConnection = dataSource.getConnection();

            // Create a SQL statement
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM emp";
            myStatement = myConnection.createStatement();

            // Execute SQL query
            myResultSet = myStatement.executeQuery(sql);

            // Process the result set
            while (myResultSet.next()) {
                String name = myResultSet.getString("ename");
                out.println(name);
            }

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: "*Table "EMP" not found*" seems pretty clear to me. There is no table name `emp` in the database you connect to. You fix this by creating the table

Comment: The postgresql JDBC driver would never throw an exception of type org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException. The H2 database driver would do that. Your configuration must have a problem. Posting the complete stack trace of the exception would help, as always.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I wouldn't post this question if there was no table emp in the database. It was there.

Comment: I have just solved the problem. What I have missed was looking up the Data Source using JNDI to obtain a connection. Here is the code I've added: `InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("PostgresDS");
            myConnection = dataSource.getConnection();`

Comment: Add this as an answer, so that the others can use these details if they encounter a similar issue. Putting your answer in a comment won't help much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just solved the problem. What I have missed was looking up the Data Source using JNDI to obtain a connection. Here is what I've added to the code in order to get a connection:

```
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/PostgresDS");
        myConnection = dataSource.getConnection();
```